# Scala is not creating private constructor for companion class

Tags: scala, companion-object

I am new to scala and trying to understand scala oops concepts.
I have create a class as :

```
class MyComp private{
    // some fields and method goes here
    }
```

when I compile it as

```
scalac MyComp.scala
```

It create a private constructor . but when I make a companion object than constructor becomes public , I am not able to understand this concept. Please clearify

here is the code for companion object for MyComp class

```
object MyComp
{
    private val comp= new MyComp;
    def getInstance= comp;
}
```

Comment: how do you asses that the constructor is public/private?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I run javap -private MyComp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JVM does not understand the concept of companion objects (and other conpects of the scala language).

Therefore, scalac has no choice but make the constructor of `MyComp` public in terms of Java bytecode, since otherwise the JVM would not allow `MyComp$` (the class of the companion of `MyComp`, often referred to as module class) to instantiate `MyComp`. This is, since `MyComp` and `MyComp$` are completely unrelated from the JVMs point of view.

Scalac tries to keep visibility modifiers on a best effort basis but sometimes must increase the visibility in the bytecode to support some rules that are specific to Scala.

Comment: but when there is no companion objects , scala is generating private constructor ?

Comment: I think simply when the companion object does not use the private constructor. So the existence of the companion does not matter.

Comment: I agree to your point as JVM point of view because when I create a another object and try to instantiate MyComp using `new` compilation error occurs

Comment: Recall that a companion object has access to the class' private members, and that the companion is compiled as a separate Java (singleton) class; therefore the constructor cannot actually be private under the Java runtime model. This is generally acceptable because the actual benefit of access modifiers is to prevent others from *accidentally* calling internal code (via compilation errors). The method is callable regardless thanks to reflection.